# SQL server, split column by commas

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Just aiming for a select query which splits a column into 5 columns separated by their comma's. The column (data_key) consistently has four comma's like this (CL,J51816940,1,789770,1), but not at the same n'th position in the field. The first, second and final column are okay, but creating column 3 and 4 is proving difficult. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
    select top 1000
left(data_key, charindex(',', data_key)-1) start,
SUBSTRING(data_key, CHARINDEX(',', data_key)+1, CHARINDEX(',', data_key, CHARINDEX(',', data_key)+1) -  CHARINDEX(',', data_key) -1 )  two, 
SUBSTRING(data_key, CHARINDEX(',', data_key, 2)+1, (charindex(',', data_key, 1))) three,
SUBSTRING(data_key, CHARINDEX(',', data_key)+1, LEN(data_key)-CHARINDEX(',', data_key)-CHARINDEX(',',REVERSE(data_key ))) four,
 RIGHT(data_key, CHARINDEX(',', REVERSE(data_key))-1) five, data_key
FROM table
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to split a comma-separated value to columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10581772/how-to-split-a-comma-separated-value-to-columns)

Comment: Storing data as comma separated values is usually a bad idea.

Comment: `CHAR_INDEX` accepts the starting position for search. So find first comma, use that position + 1 to find second comma and so on.

Comment: `SELECT JSON_VALUE(YourColAsJsonArray, '$[0]'), JSON_VALUE(YourColAsJsonArray, '$[1]'), JSON_VALUE(YourColAsJsonArray, '$[2]'), JSON_VALUE(YourColAsJsonArray, '$[3]'), JSON_VALUE(YourColAsJsonArray, '$[4]') FROM YourTable  CROSS APPLY (VALUES (CONCAT('["', REPLACE(YourCol, ',', '","'), '"]'))) V(YourColAsJsonArray)`

Comment: What is your SQL Server version?

Answer (score 1):

`CHARINDEX` takes a starting parameter. You can use `CROSS APPLY (VALUES` to feed in one value into the next

```sql
select top 1000
    left(data_key, v1.comma - 1) start,
    SUBSTRING(data_key, v1.comma + 1, v2.comma - v1.comma - 1) two, 
    SUBSTRING(data_key, v2.comma + 1, v3.comma - v2.comma - 1) three,
    SUBSTRING(data_key, v3.comma + 1, v4.comma - v3.comma - 1) four,
    SUBSTRING(data_key, v4.comma + 1, LEN(data_key)) five,
    data_key
FROM [table]
CROSS APPLY (VALUES( NULLIF(CHARINDEX(',', data_key), 0) )) v1(comma)
CROSS APPLY (VALUES( NULLIF(CHARINDEX(',', data_key, v1.comma + 1), 0) )) v2(comma)
CROSS APPLY (VALUES( NULLIF(CHARINDEX(',', data_key, v2.comma + 1), 0) )) v3(comma)
CROSS APPLY (VALUES( NULLIF(CHARINDEX(',', data_key, v3.comma + 1), 0) )) v4(comma);
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=8af31313f5c44c0956b201a1fb0fa48c)